# Star rating on simple_form doesn't send the form value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using a JQuery plugin to provide a star rating style to a field of my simple form. That's the library: http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating

I call that class in my Slim form as this:

```
td = f.input :score, label: false, input_html: {class: 'rating'}
```

And it's being displayed like this:

[image]

And that's my generated HTML form:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-vertical edit_arquivo" id="edit_arquivo_1" action="/documentos/1/arquivos/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"></form>
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="HPAt+RG4IluAdpIhsNSdMw/tFQ2PF0CzIWUGhUwkZ+AXcyy0fZOLSW+EYMAkt1m56s+KMW25aEbce/MtfNjwwA==">
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="form-group integer optional arquivo_score">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="star-rating rating-xs rating-active">
          <div class="rating-container rating-gly-star" data-content="">
            <div class="rating-stars" data-content="" style="width: 80%;"></div>
            <input class="numeric integer optional rating form-control hide" type="number" step="1" name="arquivo[score]" id="arquivo_score">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Atualizar Arquivo" class="btn btn-default btn btn-default btn-primary btn-large">
  </td>
</tr>
```

But, for some reason that I don't know why, only the parameter arquivo_score isn't being send to my controller, as my request says:

```
Started PATCH "/documentos/1/arquivos/1" for ::1 at 2015-02-20 17:18:53 -0300
Processing by ArquivosController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wB2bfSO4VgQyZ+No4zu5OY8hYgsO7WWI1GzSJ9E05LDLnpowT5P/Ft2VEYl3WH2zagP9N+xDTX0pcieP4chzkA==", "arquivo"=>{"cancelado"=>"0", "observacao"=>""}, "commit"=>"Atualizar Arquivo", "documento_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
```

Could anybody tell me what I'm missing? The difference that I can see between of that field and the others is the field data-content, but I don't know if it's related with that problem. What I' missing?

Comment: please format your html.

Comment: maybe is the form closing tag. Also, I found weird that you have a table inside a form, but table markup is incomplete.

Comment: sometimes this makes browsers to get markup out of the form or other weird behaviors.

Comment: @LearnRailsFastandFree now it sometimes send the parameter with value '0' and sometimes don't send. If i refresh the page, it sends the parameter, if I click in the button without refreshing, it doesn't send any HTTP request.

Comment: what is now? what did you change?

Comment: @LearnRailsFastandFree the same problem is occurring. I don't know what's happening. I think that's something wrong with my Js, bootstrap or both of them. For example, if I load a page and open a bootstrap modal, it goes ok, but if I click many times on that page and then try to open the same modal, the background of it starts to be more darker, as like it is loading many times. So, by those little signals, I'm trying to investigate what's happening with my bootstrap is affecting me in other places. No error or signals in console too, and I'm using https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass ...

Comment: note that your form is closing in the first line, this is not correct, it should wrap the inputs you want to send, to solve this we need you slim code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by turbolink, it will replace the body but not refresh when you just switching pages. Try to add `data-no-turbolink` in your  tag.